# Question/issue regarding video being displayed as a background in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to create a basic portfolio page that I can later change or adjust as I progress with my skillset.  I am going to paste the HTML and CSS below, but first I want to explain the issue. I am able to get elements to appear above the background video however they only appear when all the HTML is located in the header tag.  I'm a bit lost on how to get it to appear while enclosed in the body so everything is not stuck in the header. Any help would be appreciated and this is my first post to Stackoverflow so hello to everyone!

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <video id="bgVideo" poster="bgPoster.png" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
        <source src="/Lakefront.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <header class="viewport-header">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <title>Portfolio</title>

    <nav id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">About Me</a>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
        <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </nav>
    <body class="viewport-body" style="font-family: ariel,sans-serif;">
       <img id="ham" src="threelines.png" alt="hamburger menu icon" onclick="openNav()"></img>
    </body>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* The background video */
#bgVideo {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
  html, body{
    height:100%;
  }
  html{
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
   font-size: 150%;
  }

  /* Allows an overlay over the background*/
  .viewport-header {
   position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  /* keep the entire video background in frame */
  body{
  margin: 0;
  }
  /* Hamburger menu icon */
  #ham {
    text-align: right;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 90%;
    padding-top: 3%;
  }

  /* The side navigation menu */
  .sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    right: 0; /* puts the navbar to the right */
    background-color: rgba(233, 174, 64, 0.959); /* color of navbar*/
    opacity: 80%; /* makes the sidenav see through */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
  }

  /*  The navigation menu links */
  .sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
   text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
   color: #000000;
   display: block;
   transition: 0.3s;
  }

  /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
  .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
  }

  /* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
  .sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

  /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
  }
```

EDIT: When everything is properly formatted the elements do not want to appear in front of the video. Here is the code with no errors through a validator.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <title>Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <Body>
        <Main>
            <header class="viewport-header">
            <video id="bgVideo" poster="bgPoster.png" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                <source src="/Lakefront.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <nav id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
            </nav>
            <img id="ham" src="threelines.png" alt="hamburger menu icon" onclick="openNav()">
            </header>
        </Main>
    </Body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting your HTML through a validator. I've just put it through W3C validator which gave up after a bit with a Fatal error. Your structure is a bit mixed up. I can't see a head element and your video and header should probably be in the body.

Comment: The only two elements that can be direct descendants of <html> are <body> and <head>. You need to move your <header>, <nav>, and <main> elements into your <body> tag, otherwise things will definitely not work correctly. All content that you want to be visible should go inside of <body>.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get things working how I intended by putting the background in the head after using the proper formatting.  I knew that the formatting wasn't correct it was the only way I knew how to get it to work which is what I was reaching out for. Thank you for the responses though!

Answer (score -1):

First of all welcome to the community, coming to the question, you can move the header in the body.